# Text Input Column in a table in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have an output table being displayed in shiny. I would like to have a column attached to the table which would take in text input (comments) from the user for each row.

Can this be done in R shiny?

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can do some thing like this

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)


shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput("ruless"),
                  fluidRow(column(4, offset = 1, actionButton("save", "Save", width = 200)))),

  server <- function(input, output) {

    values <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)

    values$data <- as.data.frame(
      cbind(c("a", "d", "b", "c", "e", "f"),
            c(1463, 159, 54, 52, 52, 220),
            c(0.7315, 0.0795, 0.027, 0.026, 0.026, 0.11)
      )
    )

    shinyInput = function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
      #validate(need(character(len)>0,message=paste("")))
      inputs = character(len)
      for (i in seq_len(len)) {
        inputs[i] = as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label = NULL, ...))
      }
      inputs
    }

    output$ruless <- DT::renderDataTable({
      datatable(
        data.frame(delete=shinyInput(textInput,nrow(values$data),"cbox_"), values$data),
        selection="multiple",
        escape = FALSE,
        filter = list(position = 'top', clear = FALSE),
        extensions = list("ColReorder" = NULL, "Buttons" = NULL),
        options = list(
          dom = 'BRrltpi',
          autoWidth=TRUE,
          lengthMenu = list(c(10, 50, -1), c('10', '50', 'All')),
          ColReorder = TRUE,
          preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
          drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } '),
          buttons = list(
            'copy',
            'print',
            list(
              extend = 'collection',
              buttons = c('csv', 'excel', 'pdf'),
              text = 'Download',
              selected = TRUE
            )
          )
        )
      )
    })







  }
)
```

Comment: Nice answer bertil. I'm looking at building this into my app but I would like to take it one step further. Would you have suggestions how to present the user with a button that will add a column each time it is clicked (so the user can add as many columns as needed) and allow the user to also set a column name for it ?

Comment: Hi Bertil, thanks for the example. However, I could insert comments but wasn't sure how inserted comments got saved to the data table object. When I clicked copy or print, the data table that was being processed wasn't the one with the comments in. I'm interested in applying this where the user's input into the table gets saved (eventually to a central data base)--how can this be done?

Comment: Hello Bertil. I have been trying to use the values stored in those textInput fields, but with no success. I want to call, for example, the value of the first text field with input$cbox_1 (and show it in the screen with verbatimTextOutput), but it doesn't work.