# Specifying scroll options in DT::datatable affects reactivity of inputs in the table header if using renderUI

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I discovered a peculiar behavior of the datatable in Shiny R.

I am adding active inputs to the header in the datatable using approach similar to the one posted in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264943/text-input-column-in-a-table-in-shiny).
For some reason there is a difference in behavior for cases of datatable rendered directly from within `ui` and datatable rendered from `renderUI()`.

I found that both `ui` and `renderUI` ways work fine unless scrollX (or scrollY) options added to the list of options in the datatable. If scroll option is present the inputs in the datatable header in the case with `renderUI` are inactive. `ui` approach works with scroll options added.

In my case I need to use `renderUI`, so need your help with resolving this.

The code that demonstrates the behavior is below:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("text"),
  br(),
  
  splitLayout(cellWidths = 300,
              tagList(
                h3("Button from renderUI"),
                actionButton("button", label = "Press Me"),
                h3("Table without renderUI"),
                DT::datatable(
                  data = data.frame(a = letters[1:3]),
                  colnames = c(
                    as.character(
                      actionButton("button_a", label = "Button A")
                    )
                  ),
                  rownames = FALSE,
                  escape = FALSE,
                  options = list(ordering = FALSE, scrollY = TRUE,
                                 preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
                                 drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } '))
                )
              ),
              br(),
              tagList(
                h3("Button from renderUI"),
                uiOutput("custom"),
                h3("Table from renderUI"),
                uiOutput("dt"),
                br()
              )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$custom <- renderUI({
    actionButton("button_render", label = "Press Me")
  })
  
  output$dt <- renderUI({
    DT::datatable(
      data = data.frame(a = letters[1:3]),
      colnames = c(
        as.character(
          actionButton("button_b", label = "Button B")
        )
      ),
      rownames = FALSE,
      escape = FALSE,
      options = list(ordering = FALSE, scrollY = TRUE,
                     preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
                     drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } '))
    )
  })
    
  observeEvent(input$button_a, {
    output$text <- renderText(paste("button_a pressed:", input$button_a))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$button_b, {
    output$text <- renderText(paste("button_b pressed:", input$button_b))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$button_render, {
    output$text <- renderText(paste("button_render pressed:", input$button_render))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    output$text <- renderText(paste("button pressed:", input$button))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Why don't you use **renderDT** / **DTOutput** instead of **renderUI** / **uiOutput**?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent the problem happens with `renderDT/DTOutput` as well because it has to do with Shiny not registering the input. I have a sense it has to do setting the `actionButton` outside of shiny's environment. Perhaps using `insertUI()` **after** the table has been drawn could solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the UI you have to remove the JavaScript; it is useless and it throws an error.
- In the server you have to bind/unbind `table().header()`:

  ```
  options = list(
    ordering = FALSE, 
    scrollY = TRUE,
    preDrawCallback = 
      JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().header()); }'),
    drawCallback = 
      JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().header()); }')
  )
  ```
- It's more idiomatic to use `renderDT/DTOutput`.